# R: Convert Fraction to Decimal within a String

Tags: r, gsub

I want to convert some fraction characters in a string to a decimal format, but keep the context of the rest of the string, so that:

[image]

becomes:

[image]

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10677178/5195054) is similar to what I'm looking to do, but when adjusted to my use case, it doesn't keep the remainder of the string, and seems to break down entirely when used on a data frame.

```
library(gsubfn)

calc <- function(s) {
  x <- c(if (length(s) == 2) 0, as.numeric(s), 0:1)
  x[1] + x[2] / x[3]
}

ff <- c('1 1/2', '2 3/4', '2/3', '11 1/4', '5/4')
sapply(strapplyc(ff, "\\d+"), calc)
#1.5000000  2.7500000  0.6666667 11.2500000  1.2500000

ef = c('1 1/2" ant', '2 3/4" apple', '2/3" berry', '11" 1/4 plum', '5/4" orange')
sapply(strapplyc(ef, "\\d+"), calc)
#1.5000000  2.7500000  0.6666667 11.2500000  1.2500000

df <- as.data.frame(ef)
sapply(strapplyc(df$ef, "\\d+"), calc)
#2 3 4 1 5
```

Comment: Should the first one change to 1.5?

Comment: `sapply(sub(" ", "+", ff), function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))` but this the accepted answer of [this near dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480222/r-converting-data-from-fraction-to-decimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be `gsubfn`

```
gsubfn("(\\d+) (\\d+)", ~ as.numeric(x) + as.numeric(y), 
     gsubfn("(\\d+)/(\\d+)", ~ as.numeric(x)/as.numeric(y), ef))
```

Comment: Thanks, getting a `Evaluation error: is.character(x) is not TRUE.` error when I try mutate the ef column: `df %>% mutate(ef = gsubfn(...)`

Comment: @rsylatian  It is beause you column is `factor` `gsubfn` takes only `character` class.  Use `as.character(ef)`