# R: fraction of class character to decimal - other approachs don't work

Tags: r, datatable, fractions, decimalformat

sorry for the duplicate, but for some reason, the answer shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480222/r-converting-data-from-fraction-to-decimal/3480257#3480257) doesn't work for me. I´ve checked and the data table I'm working with is of character nature.

**That's my data table**

```
> dt <- data.table(V1 = c("4", "1", "0", "3"), V2 = c("0/1", "0/1", "1/2", "3/4"))

> dt
   V1  V2
1:  4 0/1
2:  1 0/1
3:  0 1/2
4:  3 3/4

> class(dt)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> class(dt$V2)
[1] "character"
```

As you see I modeled the second column so as to have elements exclusively in fraction format. I want to have the second column in decimal format, the first column as a numeric rather than character &  the final objective is to have the two columns summed up row-wise.

As I try turning it to decimal however it has no effect whatsoever on my dt - see it for yourselves

```
> FractionToDecimal <- function(x) {
+   eval(parse(text=as.character(x)))
+        x
+ }
> sapply(dt$V2, FractionToDecimal)
  0/1   0/1   1/2   3/4 
"0/1" "0/1" "1/2" "3/4" 
> FractionToDecimal(dt$V2)
[1] "0/1" "0/1" "1/2" "3/4"
```

The **other approach** I used, also doesn't work out

```
> dt %>% mutate(V2 = eval(parse(text = V2)))
  V1   V2
1  4 0.75
2  1 0.75
3  0 0.75
4  3 0.75
```

It just repeats the wrong result all over.

Does someone know where the problem lies?

If someone also knows how to have both columns turned into numeric/integer format afterward, it would also be of help!!

Thank you!!

Comment: The problem results from how you defined `FractionToDecimal()`. The `x` is redundant.

Comment: I´ve thought that that could be the case, so I've also tried out without, but still it didnt work.. Thanks for the tip tho, I always print the result at the end - will change that from now on

Comment: I mean just delete the `x` at the last line of `FractionToDecimal()`, and `sapply()` will work. It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function works but you are not changing `x` in the function and returning an unchanged `x`.

So either return output of `eval` + `parse` directly

```
FractionToDecimal <- function(x) eval(parse(text=x))
sapply(dt$V2, FractionToDecimal, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.75
```

Or store the result in `x` and return the changed `x`.

```
FractionToDecimal <- function(x) {
   x <- eval(parse(text=x))
   x
}

sapply(dt$V2, FractionToDecimal, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.75
```

Comment: Wow, I cant believe it. You're a 100% right! I've lost a lot of time, and cant believe that was the problem lol - thanks, ronak!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `sapply`.

```
dt$V2 <- sapply(dt$V2, function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
dt
#   V1   V2
# 1  4 0.00
# 2  1 0.00
# 3  0 0.50
# 4  3 0.75
```

Comment: Thank you, jay.sf - it works! I dont understand though, why applying it directly works but using a function doesn't? wasn't it supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but `parse` reads the vector "line by line", which is probably the reason that just it's last line is `eval`uated. Similar to non-vectorized, hence `sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to split with `tstrsplit` and divide

```
library(data.table)
dt[, do.call(`/`, tstrsplit(V2, "/", type.convert =TRUE))]
#[1] 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.75
```